# How to make a public EC2 IP to be allocated in an AWS Local Zone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have enabled a Local Zone (us-east-1-nyc-1a) in my region (us-east-1), then deployed an EC2 instance into that Local Zone. The public IP that was allocated to my instance, indicates it is geo-located in the parent region (N.Virginia), while I would expect it to be in the Local Zone (NY/NJ).

My CloudFormation template configuration:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
  VpcId:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
Resources:
  Ec2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0b0dcb5067f052a63
      InstanceType: t3.medium
      SubnetId: !Ref Ec2Subnet
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !GetAtt WebSecurityGroup.GroupId
  Ec2Subnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      CidrBlock: 172.31.96.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1-nyc-1a
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
  WebSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

I also tried allocating EIP in the Local Zone (and assigning it to the EC2 instance), but it also being geo-located in the parent region.

Will appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: **Side-note:** Geo-location of IP addresses is not actually possible. Instead, companies maintain databases where they 
maintain a mapping between IP addresses and locations, eg [Maxmind](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite2-free-geolocation-data?lang=en). A lot of data is collected via mobile phones, which can detect IP addresses and link it to the phone's current location. It would appear that AWS has recorded the location of their IP addresses based on the Region. It is possible that they are used across the Region rather than the Local Zone, so updating it might not be possible.

Comment: If you subscribe to AWS Support, you can open a case with them and inform them of this situation. If you subscribe to Enterprise-level Support, you can discuss it with your assigned Technical Account Manager.